# Safely linkify user generated content while escaping HTML characters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.1 removes the auto_link method. It continues to exist in a plugin, however it never quite worked as it should for UGC.

After running auto_link, you'd have to call html_safe for the links to be rendered, causing any UGC HTML to also be displayed as-is.

Is there a library that will html_escape or sanitize content AND safely linkify the text? This seems like a common use case and a bit of a pain to implement, so I figure there must be something out there.

For instance:

`<<script> do bad things </script>
http://www.google.com?q=viagra&page=1`

I'd want to end up with:

`&lt;script&gt; do bad things &lt;/script&gt;
<a href='http://www.google.com?q=viagra&amp;page=1'>http://www.google.com?q=viagra&amp;page=1</a>`

Comment: maybe you should use JS on the client side to parse URLs and convert them to links.

Comment: maybe [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize) can help?

Answer (score 0):

Redcloth (http://redcloth.org/) could be what you are looking for. It doesn't allow you to use plain html (which btw would not be a good idea anyway), but it actually supports the full textile markup language, so it is flexible as well. The redcloth textile reference (http://redcloth.org/textile/phrase-modifiers/#links) also shows how the syntax for links is. Basically, you can use it to sanitize any string you want. I myself use it for blog articles with a before_safe directive, so 
it always gets called before saving:

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
        before_save :parse_text

        def parse_text
            if RedCloth.nil?
                self.article_text = RedCloth.new(self.article_text).to_html
            end
        end
    end
```